# Run UIViewController inside UINavigationController as a second view of UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a problem trying to access a navigation controller of the view controller from it, always returns as nill to me, though it is shown within the navigation controller.
Here is what I have (I have a split view controller, that is presented as tab controller for master  and viewcontroller (inside navigation controller) as detail):

```
FirstDetailViewController *fdvc = [[FirstDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *fdvcNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fdvc];

NSArray *ipadVCs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tabController, fdvcNav, nil];
UISplitViewController *splitvc = [[UISplitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[splitvc setViewControllers:ipadVCs];
[[splitvc view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splitViewControllerBG"]]];
[splitvc setDelegate:fdvc];

[[self window] setRootViewController:splitvc];
[[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
```

But when I'm trying to access a navigation controller from the fdvc view controller in ViewDidLoad with [self navigationController] it gives me (Null) always.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Turned out, that I had to move my code from ViewDidLoad method to ViewDidAppear and it worked fine.

viewDidLoad is getting called before the navigationController property has been updated, that was my mistake.